# Display markdown files sequentially grouped by page

Tags: database, markdown, local, personal-data, knowledge-management

When I take notes I use markdown files.

I would like to read my notes all together in cronological order, maybe grouped by pages that contains 25 notes per page. Is there a way to achieve this in a relatively "user friendly" simple way?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Better suited at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/unanswered I don't know how Discord is an answer to this question, as its Markdown support isn't great, so you'll also need to be more detailed.